# Xerces XPath causes seg fault when path doesn't exist

Tags: c++, xml, xpath, xerces

I can successfully use Xerces XPath feature to query for information from an XML with the following XML and C++ code.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<root>
    <ApplicationSettings>
        hello universe
    </ApplicationSettings>
</root>
```

**C++**

```
int main()
{
  XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize();
  // create the DOM parser
  XercesDOMParser *parser = new XercesDOMParser;
  parser->setValidationScheme(XercesDOMParser::Val_Never);
  parser->parse("fake_cmf.xml");
  // get the DOM representation
  DOMDocument *doc = parser->getDocument();
  // get the root element
  DOMElement* root = doc->getDocumentElement();

  // evaluate the xpath
  DOMXPathResult* result=doc->evaluate(
      XMLString::transcode("/root/ApplicationSettings"), // <-- HERE IS THE XPATH
      root,
      NULL,
      DOMXPathResult::ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, //DOMXPathResult::ANY_UNORDERED_NODE_TYPE, //DOMXPathResult::STRING_TYPE,
      NULL);

  // look into the xpart evaluate result
  result->snapshotItem(0);
  std::cout<<TranscodeToStr(result->getNodeValue()->getFirstChild()->getNodeValue(),"ascii").str()<<std::endl;;

  XMLPlatformUtils::Terminate();
 return 0;
}
```

The problem is that sometimes my XML will only have certain fields. But if I remove the `ApplicationSettings` entry from the XML it will seg fault. How can I properly handle these optional fields? I know that trying to correct from seg faults is risky business.

Comment: Are you sure the fault lies in Xerces rather than in your code where you neglect to check `result` before dereferencing it?

Comment: @kjhughes I am not sure at all. Let me find out.

Comment: @kjhughes Okay `result` is not `NULL` and contains the same `ResultType` regardless of whether the XPath exists, so that part is okay. However, I think investigating that has lead me to a solution. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The seg fault is occurring in this line

```
 std::cout<<TranscodeToStr(result->getNodeValue()->getFirstChild()->getNodeValue(),"ascii").str()<<std::endl;
```

specifically in get `getFirstChild()` call because the result of `getNodeValue()` is `NULL`.

This is my quick and dirty solution. It's not really ideal but it works. I would prefer a more sophisticated evaluation and response.

```
if (result->getNodeValue() == NULL)
{
  cout << "There is no result for the provided XPath " << endl;
}
else
{
  cout<<TranscodeToStr(result->getNodeValue()->getFirstChild()->getNodeValue(),"ascii").str()<<endl;
}
```